# Acotar zona con Xamarin Forms (XAML)

Tags: xamarin, xaml

Quiero acotar una zona específica de una imagen. Se supone que esta área va a ser más oscura que el resto. ¿Cómo lo consigo con Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Una posible solucion es usar un Grid, para que los elementos que insertes se pisen unos a otros, espero que conozcas como usarlo, luego de colocar la imagen puede colocar un Boxview y le da opacity="0.5" esto le dara cierta transparencia y estara encima de la imagen y oscurecera tu imagen.